# How to delete and insert into child dependent table (hibernate)?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have one table and it has one child dependent table. This is what i want, whenever I update the entry in the main table, it should delete the entries from child dependent table( the dependent values) and insert the new ones. How can I do that.
I am using

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true,
```

But that is just keep inserting new ones or updating the exisiting ones. This is not ideal for me. As sometimes, the old values remain there which are no longer valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping should be like mentioned-below:

```
class Parent{

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Child> childs = new ArrayList<Child>();
    
    ---
    
    }

class Child{
--
}
```

You have achieve this manual by clearing the child records first and creating the new records whenever you update the parent entity.

```
 updateParent(){
    childs.clear()
    createNewChild();
    setNewChildsInParentEntity();
    }
```

Comment: childs.clear only clears the list, doesnt execute the sql. or am I missing something here

Comment: if you are executing the operation in hibernate session then it will automatically remove all the elements, or you can forcefully delete all the childs by using their Id.

Comment: i am sorry, i am new to hibernate. it is not clear to me. I am doing exactly what you are saying. childs.clear is some figurative term ? as in do i need to expand on the method here? because I am doing childs.clear when i try to update the parent and it does nothing other than clearing the child list